# Создание программно БД и таблицу в C#. Ошибка: Data Source cannot be empty

Tags: c#, sqlite

Хочу создать БД и таблицу в C#. БД - SQLite. Написал так:

```
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("D:\\data.db");
        string databaseName = @"D:\\data.db";
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Sourse={0};", databaseName));
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE data ([text] char(1000) NOT NULL);", connection);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

Указывает на connection.Open(); ошибкой:
Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database

Как это исправить?

Comment: никто не поможет?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039720/c-sharp-sqlite-what-is-data-source-cannot-be-empty-use-memory-to-open-an надеюсь то что нужно

Answer (score 6):

У вас в строке:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Sourse={0};", databaseName));
```

написано

> Data Sourse

а надо

> Data Source

Неправильный синтаксис строки подключения.

**UPDATED**: ещё в некоторых случаях нужно указание версии в ConnectionString. Строка должна выглядеть полностью так:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}; Version=3;", databaseName));
```

**P.S.** Но вообще я скачал последний SQLite из репозитория NuGet и у меня всё без указания версии работает.

**UPDATED 2**: работающий код с [библиотекой версии 1.0.83.0](http://www.sendspace.com/file/yf8olg):

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("D:\\data.db");
string databaseName = @"D:\\data.db";
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}; Version=3;", databaseName));
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE data ([text] char(1000) NOT NULL);", connection);
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: нет. То же самое. Не от этого зависит

Comment: @navi1893 Обновил ответ. Ещё нужен в строке подключения версия.

Comment: опять ничего. Так же пишет @Drac5

Comment: @navi1893 а какую библиотеку используете? точно оригинальную? А версию?

Comment: ну да. А вы можете мне свои библиотеки отправить?

Comment: @navi1893 Я брал свою из репозитория NuGet. Они отлично в этом случае присоединяются к проекту и без лишних проблем.
Вот версия SQLite.dll из репозитория : http://www.sendspace.com/file/yf8olg

Comment: SQLite из Nuget-a отличный выбор.